# Alternative for “das Bewundertwerden”

Tags: single-word-request, nominalization

*Das Bewundertwerden* as a nominalisation of *bewundert werden* *(to be admired)* is not a very clever form I think. It can probably be expressed with a single noun.

I think the problem is that I first need to find a verb for *Bewunderung erhalten* or *bewundert werden* and than form its nominalisation.

Does anyone know a proper word for *bewundert werden* or *Bewunderung erhalten?*

Comment: What do you need it for? It is often much easier to rephrase the whole sentence.

Comment: You may even end back at *Bewunderung*, e.g., *Herbert genoss das Bewundertwerden* is just *Herbert genoss die Bewunderung*.

Comment: _Popularität, Aufmerksamkeit, Anerkennung, Verehrung_ are similar to _Bewunderung_, but not quite the same. A common expression to distinguish between the subject being the admirer or the admired is the relative clause _die ihm [plötzlich/jetzt/nun] zuteil/entgegengebracht wurde_.

Comment: "Bewunderung" is not enough. Like in this example: *Was ist dir wichtiger: Das Bewundertwerden oder Bewundern?*

Answer (score 1):

Angehimmelt werden.

Verehrt werden.

Meine Frage wäre. Warum willst du das Wort "Bewundertwerden benutzen?"

Schreibst du eine Abhandlung über das Bewundertwerden?

Besser wäre es zu schreiben: "Er mochte es bewundert zu werden." Oder: "Er liebte die Bewunderung, die Ihm von seinen Bewunderern zu teil wurde."

Bewundertwerden ist passiv. "Bewundert zu werden" ist auch passiv und ist meines Erachtens die bessere alternative.

Bewundert zu werden hat nicht nur Vorteile.